Terraform output: how to get the first item from a container if any exists
The documentation of a Terraform provider says that I can get the value from a container in this way .identity[0] but in some cases identity is empty. How can I get the first element if at least one is in the container (otherwise null for example).
A error (and the errored line) met in actual case because of it:
Error: Invalid index
  on .../outputs.tf line 21, in output "container_registry_primary_identity_principal_id":
  21:     value = azurerm_container_registry.***.identity[0].principal_id
    ├────────────────
    │ azurerm_container_registry.***.identity is empty list of object
The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the
collection has no elements.


You could maybe achieve what you want by using the try built-in function. Since you haven't added the entire output block, that should look something like the following:
output "container_registry_primary_identity_principal_id" {
  value = try(azurerm_container_registry.***.identity[0].principal_id, null)
}


On one hand it is a little too broad for the question but my actual case it works perfectly. Thank you!

The "splat operator" [*] can be used to start with a list of objects and produce a list of the values of just one attribute of those objects:
azurerm_container_registry.example.identity[*].principal_id

The result of that expression would be a list of the same length as azurerm_container_registry.example.identity, but with the elements just being principal_id values.
If you know that this list will always have either zero or one elements (never more than one) then you can use the one function to convert that into either a single value or null:
one(azurerm_container_registry.example.identity[*].principal_id)

You might notice that the example under Relationship to the "Splat" operator is very similar to your goal. Here's a similar example for an output block like the one your error message implies:
output "container_registry_primary_identity_principal_id" {
  value = one(azurerm_container_registry.example.identity[*].principal_id)
}


Thank you very much for the answer, the details and the links!
